# VBA to find a specified cell value in specified range and select it

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am having trouble creating a macro that will find a specified value in my active sheet within a range in my "Information" sheet. If the cell value us not found in the range then it will give me a message box stating "Value not Found" I have the following but it is not working:

```vb
Sub testrot()
    Dim i As String
    Dim srchrng As Range

    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select
    i = Cells(2, 5)
    Sheets("Information").Select
    Set srchrng = Range("j8:j17").Find(what = i)
    If Not srchrng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

The cell (2,5) in my active sheet is for example #16, and in the range (j8:j17) it is a list of different strings #16, #17, etc.

I appreciate any advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid `.Select`/`.Activate`

```
Sub testRot2()
Dim str As String
Dim srchRng As Range
With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    str = .Cells(2, 5).Value
    Set srchRng = .Range("J8:J17").Find(what:=str)
    If srchRng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Also, note that I changed `i` to `str`. This is a personal choice, as I typically see `i` as a `Long`/`Integer` for looping. You can keep it `i` though, just thought to mention it.  Also, note the colon required in `Find(what:=str)`.

Comment: `Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)` is the same as `ActiveSheet`

Comment: @BruceWayne this works to the point I get the MsgBox but it does not reference the "Information" tab where the rage is found to select the cell in the range with  the str value. My sheet1 tab has cell (2,5) with value #16 and I want to select it in the "information tab" within the range. I tried setting up `Sheets ("Information").Select before the set code but not recognizing it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @deejaay - Ah, I think you just need to add the worksheet before the search range:  `Set srchRng = Sheets("Information").Range("J8:J17").Find(what:=str)`.  This will search the "Information" sheet for the string found in the ActiveSheet's Cell `E2`.