# How do I use VBA to select a cell in a specified range, that matches the value of another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Example:
In cells A1:A12 I have the months of the year.
In cell B1 I have the text "July"
I would like some help with VBA code that selects the cell within range A1:A12 that matches whatever I have in B1.

In this instance the VBA selection would be A7.
**Apologies** the VBA should select G1

Could somebody please help?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40030972/11683

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Application.Match("July",ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"),0)).Select`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Dim MyValue As Range
Dim Result As Range

Set MyRange = Range("A1:A12)
Set MyValue = Range("B1)

For Each cell In MyRange

        If cell.Value = MyValue.Valu Then
            Set Result = cell
            Result.Select
            Exit For
        End If

Next cell
```

Comment: Looping ranges is the slowest method.  The linked answer uses find, which will be much faster

Comment: @ScottCraner in this use case it doesn't really matter, you have 12 cells

Comment: It was a statement, you are correct, in this instance but if the 12 cells becomes 1000 it will make a difference, why not practice the best methods even when it does not make a difference?  One line of Find is much faster and less typing than a loop.